# Bummer, something went wrong Linkedln Auth

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization

I want to make a login and register, I can enter via social media LinkedIn. but i have problem unable to login

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT7pn.png)

and this is the configuration in the linkedln developer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJlzU.png)

I have also added a request to the product

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqpde.png)

but still error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atx1V.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.